HQL could not resolve property error - no typos that I can find
I'm having some problems with my HQL query. I want to get 10 posts from the database using Hibernate.
My mapping:
@Entity
@Table(name = "bl_post", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "post_id"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "post_text"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "user_id"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "datePub")
})
public class Post implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column( name = "post_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long postId;
    @Transient
    private ObjectStatus statusPost;
    @Column(name = "post_title", length = 255)
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "post_text", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 25000)
    private String text;
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;
//    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
    @Column(name = "datePub", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime dateOfPublish;
    @Transient
    private List<Comment> postComments;

    public Post() {

    }

My query is:
 TypedQuery<Post> query = em.createQuery(
                    "FROM Post p ORDER BY p.datePub DESC", Post.class);
            query.setMaxResults(10);
             posts = query.getResultList();

And the error that it throws is:
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: datePub of: service.domian.Post

(domian is the spelling I use elsewhere, that is not a typo)
I have made double certain that there no typos that I can find. I also tried changing the names, etc. This must be something very obvious but I just can't see it.

Have you tried dateOfPublish instead? I'm not 100% sure, but Hibernate relies on the entities, where you have mapped to the db column with datePub.
